# Is it possible to change the background-color of the focus inputfield in angularjs and css

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a selectlist that gets focused on if nothing is selected in the selectlist on button click.It works fine and the default color is blue.I need to change the background-color to red is it possible?
Here is my code
html

```
 <select focus-on="focusMe">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
```

js

```
   ngAppModule.directive('focusOn', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                focusMe: '=focusOn'
            },
            link: function (scope, elt, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('focusMe', function (val) {
                    if (val) {
                        elt[0].focus();
                        scope.focusMe = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
    ]);
```

css

```
select[focus-on] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: i didnt understand, is this fine?? http://jsfiddle.net/x2cy4aeg/4/

Comment: @Manjunath Siddappa nope.I have a button that you click on it and if no option is selected the background-color must be red.

Comment: please create jsfiddle with whole code??

Answer (score 0):

try ng-class.

So the HTML will look like

```
<select focus-on="focusMe" ng-class={red:focusMe}>
```

and in CSS

```
red {
 background-color: red;
}
```